# Intellij - running a project after java upgrade fails

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a project with 3 modules. I am running them with Intellij. Everything worked fine until project was upgraded to java 17, I ran following commands in terminal:

```
sdk install java 17.0.3-tem
sdk use java 17.0.3-tem
```

In Intellij preferences **Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Project bytcode version** is set to 17 as well as all per module bytecode target versions.

I have tried to use both **javac** and **eclipse** compiler, also I have set the Gradle Jvm to `temurin-17` in Intellij **Build Tools -> Gradle**, but I still get an error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class glow.MainKt
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myproject/MainKt has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 58.0
```

What else do I need to do in order to get rid of this error?

Comment: Please provide screenshots from "File | Project Structure | Project" and "File | Project Structure | Modules | module_name | Dependencies". Try to delete the target/build/out directory from the project and rebuild